# What has changed for $this->auth->authorize (cakephp 1.3) in CakePHP 2.2.1 (stable)?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am upgrading an app from CakePHP 1.3 to CakePHP 2.2.1 .

We are implementing ACL and in AppController I saw

```
if (isset($this->Auth)) {
            if ($this->use_acl) {
                $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';
            }
```

As a variable declaration I have already made changes to the following :

```
var $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')
                )
            ),
            'loginAction' => array(
                'admin' => false, 'prefix' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 
                'action' => 'login')
        ),
        'Session', 'Facebook.Connect');
```

does it still require me to keep:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => false, 'prefix' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

The code work may sound ugly but, that is how upgrades are! ;)

Also, can I use the $this->Auth-> 'auth properties' in 2.2.1 as it was possible in 1.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the best place to get started with questions like this is [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html). Then, post the results of your tests rather than your code and a broad question.

That said, the first block of code you posted looks like a custom variable on your end `$this->use_acl`.  I've never seen that used in CakePHP, so there's some flag your setting in your app to use 'actions'.

The second block of code looks pretty standard.  It should work.  Yes, you still need to specify a login action so that when a user tries to navigate to a page that is protected, then he/she will be redirected to the login.  That said, there are differences in the login process as noted in the manual link above.  You should take a look at the differences as to when a password is hashed and the login() function itself as they both have changed.  The fact you are using ACL shouldn't matter much as far as Authentication differences between the two version.

Your last question `Also, can I use the $this->Auth-> 'auth properties' in 2.2.1 as it was possible in 1.3 ?`, the answer is yes.  You should take a look at the `AuthComponent.php` file in the lib/Cake folder.  It's heavily commented about the information you are asking about here.  There are even examples.

Comment: Well, this code isn't done by me. It is given to me for an update. When I run the code, it returns 500 error which i will solve after I refactor the codebase, whilst refactoring I came across this. I checked the manual and mentally I am between 1.3 and 2.x (you understand that right?). I am following http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html and ofc the manual link which you already gave. Yes, use_acl did bug me too. So bottomline, nothing much has changed?

Comment: Not much has changed with how you setup the Auth component.  However, the way that it handles the authentication has completely changed.  The manual has flags in there describing how the two differ.  Namely, you need to hash your passwords before saving and the login() method has changed.  So, you absolutely will need to change your app to account for that. But, given that we don't have access to how the Auth component is used throughout your app, it's impossible to say that you can fix your issues by changing a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks @Scott . I will am facing lot of issues at the moment. But, Auth will have to be meticulously done.

Comment: @KarmicDice How did this upgrade turn out for you? I'm also upgrading from 1.3 to 2.x (2.2.4) and am receiving a 500 error.

Comment: To be simple. How I did was... created a base CakePHP 2x on the system and later, cherry picked controllers, views, models... one unit, at a time... It took me about 3 weeks for the transition but, now all good :)